# Translate part of the website with google

Tags: php, web, translate

I have some text on my website. Part of this text is in another language (German). My primary language is Slovenian. Is it possible to translate only the German part of the text with google translate? Is it possible to translate it automatically (without user knowing it that you are translating)?

Comment: Try to give a look here : [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

Comment: I spotted this before. Does anyone use this API? Do you have bad experience with it? I really need reliable API.

Comment: It's the official Google API to deal with Google Translate, how could you expect better ?

Comment: Well in 50% translates aren't correct (at least to my language). This is why I expect it better.

Comment: Ah right, so you're not looking for a Google translate API, but for advices on translation APIs. In that case, asking for recommendations is just off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provide API for translate. Check that here.

[Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

You have an example in PHP in this site

[Using Google Translate API with PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/)

You can do it with javascript itself. So you can do it without even loading the server. But there is limit for the conversion when you are using Google translate API as 2,000,000 characters per day. If you want to have more conversion rates than this, the you might have to pay.